# Elastic Search MoreLikeThis Query Never Returns Results

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I must be doing something fundamentally wrong here.  I'm trying to get a "More Like This" query working in a search engine project we have that uses Elastic Search. The idea is that the CMS can write tags (like categories) to the page in a Meta tag or something, and we would read those into Elastic and use them to drive a "more like this" search based upon an input document id.

So if the input document has tags of `catfish, chicken, goat` I would expect Elastic Search to find other documents that share those tags and not return ones for `racecar` and `airplane`.

I've built a proof of concept console app by:

- Getting a local Elastic Search 6.6.1 instance running in Docker by following the instructions on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html
- Creating a new .NET Framework 4.6.1 Console App
- Adding the NuGet packages for NEST 6.5.0 and ElasticSearch.Net 6.5.0

Then I created a new elastic index that contains objects (Type "MyThing") that have a "Tags" property.  This tag is a random comma-delimited set of words from a set of possible values.  I've inserted anywhere from 100 to 5000 items in the index in testing. I've tried more and fewer possible words in the set.

No matter what I try the `MoreLikeThis` query never returns anything, and I don't understand why.

**Query that isn't returning results:**

```
    var result = EsClient.Search<MyThing>(s => s
        .Index(DEFAULT_INDEX)
        .Query(esQuery =>
        {
            var mainQuery = esQuery
                .MoreLikeThis(mlt => mlt
                    .Include(true)
                    .Fields(f => f.Field(ff => ff.Tags, 5))
                    .Like(l => l.Document(d => d.Id(id)))
                );

            return mainQuery;
        }
```

**Full "program.cs" source:**

```
using Nest;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test_MoreLikeThis_ES6
{
    class Program
    {
        public class MyThing
        {
            public string Tags { get; set; }
        }

        const string ELASTIC_SERVER = "http://localhost:9200";
        const string DEFAULT_INDEX = "my_index";
        const int NUM_RECORDS = 1000;

        private static Uri es_node = new Uri(ELASTIC_SERVER);
        private static ConnectionSettings settings = new ConnectionSettings(es_node).DefaultIndex(DEFAULT_INDEX);
        private static ElasticClient EsClient = new ElasticClient(settings);

        private static Random rnd = new Random();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Rebuild index? (y):");
            var answer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            if (answer == "y")
            {
                RebuildIndex();
                for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RECORDS; i++)
                {
                    AddToIndex();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Getting a Thing...");
            var aThingId = GetARandomThingId();


            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Looking for something similar to document with id " + aThingId);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            GetMoreLikeAThing(aThingId);
        }

        private static string GetARandomThingId()
        {
            var firstdocQuery = EsClient
                .Search<MyThing>(s =>
                    s.Size(1)
                    .Query(q => {
                        return q.FunctionScore(fs => fs.Functions(fn => fn.RandomScore(rs => rs.Seed(DateTime.Now.Ticks).Field("_seq_no"))));
                    })
                );

            if (!firstdocQuery.IsValid || firstdocQuery.Hits.Count == 0) return null;

            var hit = firstdocQuery.Hits.First();
            Console.WriteLine("Found a thing with id '" + hit.Id + "' and tags: " + hit.Source.Tags);
            return hit.Id;
        }

        private static void GetMoreLikeAThing(string id)
        {

            var result = EsClient.Search<MyThing>(s => s
                .Index(DEFAULT_INDEX)
                .Query(esQuery =>
                {
                    var mainQuery = esQuery
                        .MoreLikeThis(mlt => mlt
                            .Include(true)
                            .Fields(f => f.Field(ff => ff.Tags, 5))
                            .Like(l => l.Document(d => d.Id(id)))
                        );

                    return mainQuery;
                }

            ));

            if (result.IsValid)
            {
                if (result.Hits.Count > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("These things are similar:");
                    foreach (var hit in result.Hits)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("   " + hit.Id + " : " + hit.Source.Tags);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No similar things found.");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There was an error running the ES query.");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter (y) to get another thing, or anything else to exit");
            var y = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            if (y == "y")
            {
                var aThingId = GetARandomThingId();
                GetMoreLikeAThing(aThingId);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        private static void RebuildIndex()
        {
            var existsResponse = EsClient.IndexExists(DEFAULT_INDEX);
            if (existsResponse.Exists) //delete existing mapping (and data)
            {
                EsClient.DeleteIndex(DEFAULT_INDEX);
            }

            var rebuildResponse = EsClient.CreateIndex(DEFAULT_INDEX, c => c.Settings(s => s.NumberOfReplicas(1).NumberOfShards(5)));
            var response2 = EsClient.Map<MyThing>(m => m.AutoMap());
        }

        private static void AddToIndex()
        {
            var myThing = new MyThing();
            var tags = new List<string> {
                    "catfish",
                    "tractor",
                    "racecar",
                    "airplane",
                    "chicken",
                    "goat",
                    "pig",
                    "horse",
                    "goose",
                    "duck"
                };

            var randNum = rnd.Next(0, tags.Count);

            //get randNum random tags
            var rand = tags.OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).Take(randNum);
            myThing.Tags = string.Join(", ", rand);

            var ir = new IndexRequest<MyThing>(myThing);
            var indexResponse = EsClient.Index(ir);

            Console.WriteLine("Index response: " + indexResponse.Id + " : " + string.Join(" " , myThing.Tags));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the default `min_term_freq` value of 2 will never be satisfied for any of the terms of the prototype document because all documents contain only each tag (*term*) once. If you drop `min_term_freq` to 1, you'll get results. Might also want to set `min_doc_freq` to 1 too, and combine with a query that excludes the prototype document.

Here's an example to play with

```cs
const string ELASTIC_SERVER = "http://localhost:9200";
const string DEFAULT_INDEX = "my_index";
const int NUM_RECORDS = 1000;

private static readonly Random _random = new Random();
private static readonly IReadOnlyList<string> Tags = 
    new List<string>
    {
        "catfish",
        "tractor",
        "racecar",
        "airplane",
        "chicken",
        "goat",
        "pig",
        "horse",
        "goose",
        "duck"
    };

private static ElasticClient _client;

private static void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(ELASTIC_SERVER));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(DEFAULT_INDEX);

    _client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    Console.WriteLine("Rebuild index? (y):");
    var answer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    if (answer == "y")
    {
        RebuildIndex();
        AddToIndex();
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Getting a Thing...");
    var aThingId = GetARandomThingId();

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Looking for something similar to document with id " + aThingId);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();

    GetMoreLikeAThing(aThingId);
}

public class MyThing
{
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
}

private static string GetARandomThingId()
{
    var firstdocQuery = _client
        .Search<MyThing>(s =>
            s.Size(1)
            .Query(q => q
                .FunctionScore(fs => fs
                    .Functions(fn => fn
                        .RandomScore(rs => rs
                            .Seed(DateTime.Now.Ticks)
                            .Field("_seq_no")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );

    if (!firstdocQuery.IsValid || firstdocQuery.Hits.Count == 0) return null;

    var hit = firstdocQuery.Hits.First();
    Console.WriteLine($"Found a thing with id '{hit.Id}' and tags: {string.Join(", ", hit.Source.Tags)}");
    return hit.Id;
}

private static void GetMoreLikeAThing(string id)
{
    var result = _client.Search<MyThing>(s => s
        .Index(DEFAULT_INDEX)
        .Query(esQuery => esQuery 
            .MoreLikeThis(mlt => mlt
                    .Include(true)
                    .Fields(f => f.Field(ff => ff.Tags))
                    .Like(l => l.Document(d => d.Id(id)))
                    .MinTermFrequency(1)
                    .MinDocumentFrequency(1)
            ) && !esQuery
            .Ids(ids => ids
                .Values(id)
            )
        )
    );

    if (result.IsValid)
    {
        if (result.Hits.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("These things are similar:");
            foreach (var hit in result.Hits)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"   {hit.Id}: {string.Join(", ", hit.Source.Tags)}");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No similar things found.");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There was an error running the ES query.");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter (y) to get another thing, or anything else to exit");
    var y = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

    if (y == "y")
    {
        var aThingId = GetARandomThingId();
        GetMoreLikeAThing(aThingId);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Any key to exit...");

}

private static void RebuildIndex()
{
    var existsResponse = _client.IndexExists(DEFAULT_INDEX);
    if (existsResponse.Exists) //delete existing mapping (and data)
    {
        _client.DeleteIndex(DEFAULT_INDEX);
    }

    var rebuildResponse = _client.CreateIndex(DEFAULT_INDEX, c => c
        .Settings(s => s
            .NumberOfShards(1)
        )
        .Mappings(m => m       
            .Map<MyThing>(mm => mm.AutoMap())
        )
    );
}

private static void AddToIndex()
{
    var bulkAllObservable = _client.BulkAll(GetMyThings(), b => b
        .RefreshOnCompleted()
        .Size(1000));

    var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    Exception exception = null;

    var bulkAllObserver = new BulkAllObserver(
        onNext: r =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Indexed page {r.Page}");
        },
        onError: e => 
        {
            exception = e;
            waitHandle.Set();
        },
        onCompleted: () => waitHandle.Set());

    bulkAllObservable.Subscribe(bulkAllObserver);

    waitHandle.WaitOne();

    if (exception != null)
    {
        throw exception;
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<MyThing> GetMyThings()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RECORDS; i++)
    {
        var randomTags = Tags.OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            .Take(_random.Next(0, Tags.Count))
            .OrderBy(t => t)
            .ToList();

        yield return new MyThing { Tags = randomTags };
    }
}
```

And here's an example output

```
Found a thing with id 'Ugg9LGkBPK3n91HQD1d5' and tags: airplane, goat
These things are similar:
   4wg9LGkBPK3n91HQD1l5: airplane, goat
   9Ag9LGkBPK3n91HQD1l5: airplane, goat
   Vgg9LGkBPK3n91HQD1d5: airplane, goat, goose
   sQg9LGkBPK3n91HQD1d5: airplane, duck, goat
   lQg9LGkBPK3n91HQD1h5: airplane, catfish, goat
   9gg9LGkBPK3n91HQD1l5: airplane, catfish, goat
   FQg9LGkBPK3n91HQD1p5: airplane, goat, goose
   Jwg9LGkBPK3n91HQD1p5: airplane, goat, goose
   Fwg9LGkBPK3n91HQD1d5: airplane, duck, goat, tractor
   Kwg9LGkBPK3n91HQD1d5: airplane, goat, goose, horse
```

Comment: That was it man, thanks!  I swear I tried that too, I was fiddling with all those max/min options, and reading that doc page, but clearly I never got the right combo.